# How to add links to sidebar in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar

I would like to add links to the sidebar of my pages in Sphinx. How do I go about doing this. I have around 4 pages and I want them to be accessible from each others pages without using the search feature.

Similar to this:
https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#table-of-contents

with the previous and next topic.

Comment: Are the links actual Previous and Next links that change according to the current page, or a fixed part of the template?

Comment: They should change based on the current page.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Next and Previous links are available in most themes, but a couple require additional configuration. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html Also ensure you have a [`toctree` directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/markup/toctree.html).